# how to prevent some tables from shrinking when the largest cannot shrink any further?

Tags: css

I am working on a layout that contains multiple tables, some of which have more columns than others. The width of the container is unknown at design time, but when it is wide enough to fit all columns in the widest table, all tables are aligned. As the width of the container decreases, all tables shrink horizontally for as long as they have enough white space to do so. When the largest table cannot shrink any further, it overflows and the container shows an appropriate horizontal scroll bar. However, the rest of the tables keep shrinking while they have enough room to do so, so I lose the alignment between them.

I would like all tables to stop shrinking when the largest one cannot shrink further. Is that possible?

```css
article {
  margin:0 40px;
}

article>table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 90%;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

article>table+table.cont {
  border-top:none;
}

article>table>thead {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

article>table>thead td {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #cfe0e6;
  color: #1a1b1f;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom:3px;
}

article>table>tbody>tr>td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: background-color .3s;
}

article>table>tbody>tr>td:not(:first-child) {
  text-align:right;
  width:1px
}

article>table tr>td:not(:first-child) {
  padding:0 5px
}
```

```html
<article>
   <h2>Section title</h2>
   <table>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Units</td>
            <td>Unit price</td>
            <td>Subtotal</td>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>Item 1 relatively long name</td>
            <td><span class="vl">3,530</span></td>
            <td><span class="vl">0.130848</span></td>
            <td><span class="vl">461.89</span></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Item 2 relatively long name</td>
            <td><span class="vl">3,459</span></td>
            <td><span class="vl">0.108193</span></td>
            <td><span class="vl">374.24</span></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Item 3 relatively long name</td>
            <td><span class="vl">1,831</span></td>
            <td><span class="vl">0.074858</span></td>
            <td><span class="vl">137.06</span></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <table>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Units</td>
            <td>Period</td>
            <td>Unit price</td>
            <td>Subtotal</td>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>Item 4 relatively long name</td>
            <td><span class="vl">49.000</span></td>
            <td><span class="vl">24</span></td>
            <td><span class="vl">0.108735</span></td>
            <td><span class="vl">127.87</span></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Item 5 relatively long name</td>
            <td><span class="vl">51.300</span></td>
            <td><span class="vl">24</span></td>
            <td><span class="vl">0.065241</span></td>
            <td><span class="vl">80.32</span></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Item 6 relatively long name</td>
            <td><span class="vl">47.000</span></td>
            <td><span class="vl">24</span></td>
            <td><span class="vl">0.043494</span></td>
            <td><span class="vl">49.06</span></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <table>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Units</td>
            <td>Unit price</td>
            <td>Subtotal</td>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>Item 7 relatively long name</td>
            <td><span class="vl">599</span></td>
            <td><span class="vl">0.041554</span></td>
            <td><span class="vl">24.89</span></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Item 8 relatively long name</td>
            <td><span class="vl">611</span></td>
            <td><span class="vl">0.041554</span></td>
            <td><span class="vl">25.39</span></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td><span class="vl cal">1,280.72</span></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</article>
```

Comment: you can go with `max-width` and `min-width` in CSS and manipulate the table width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular `div`s and `max-with` won't do the trick here, because you would need to tell your parent container to adapt to its child's largest dimension. However, that's something CSS can't do, because it's cascading parent **➞** children, not the other way round.

A neat workaround/trick is to encapsulate all your tables in one global table with one cell :

```css
article {
  margin: 0 40px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

td.oneCell{
   border: red dashed 2px;
}

article table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 90%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

article table+table.cont {
  border-top: none;
}

article table>thead {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

article table>thead td {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #cfe0e6;
  color: #1a1b1f;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

article table>tbody>tr>td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: background-color .3s;
}

article table>tbody>tr>td:not(:first-child) {
  text-align: right;
  width: 1px
}

article table tr>td:not(:first-child) {
  padding: 0 5px
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h2>Section title</h2>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="oneCell">
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Units</td>
                <td>Unit price</td>
                <td>Subtotal</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Item 1 relatively long name</td>
                <td><span class="vl">3,530</span></td>
                <td><span class="vl">0.130848</span></td>
                <td><span class="vl">461.89</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Item 2 relatively long name</td>
                <td><span class="vl">3,459</span></td>
                <td><span class="vl">0.108193</span></td>
                <td><span class="vl">374.24</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Item 3 relatively long name</td>
                <td><span class="vl">1,831</span></td>
                <td><span class="vl">0.074858</span></td>
                <td><span class="vl">137.06</span></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Units</td>
                <td>Period</td>
                <td>Unit price</td>
                <td>Subtotal</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Item 4 relatively long name</td>
                <td><span class="vl">49.000</span></td>
                <td><span class="vl">24</span></td>
                <td><span class="vl">0.108735</span></td>
                <td><span class="vl">127.87</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Item 5 relatively long name</td>
                <td><span class="vl">51.300</span></td>
                <td><span class="vl">24</span></td>
                <td><span class="vl">0.065241</span></td>
                <td><span class="vl">80.32</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Item 6 relatively long name</td>
                <td><span class="vl">47.000</span></td>
                <td><span class="vl">24</span></td>
                <td><span class="vl">0.043494</span></td>
                <td><span class="vl">49.06</span></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Units</td>
                <td>Unit price</td>
                <td>Subtotal</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Item 7 relatively long name</td>
                <td><span class="vl">599</span></td>
                <td><span class="vl">0.041554</span></td>
                <td><span class="vl">24.89</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Item 8 relatively long name</td>
                <td><span class="vl">611</span></td>
                <td><span class="vl">0.041554</span></td>
                <td><span class="vl">25.39</span></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Total</td>
                <td><span class="vl cal">1,280.72</span></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</article>
```

However you also need to edit your CSS as I did, because at the moment it's targeting specifically first-level tables within `<article>`, Make it a bit more flexible by targeting any table. Replace `article>table` with `article table` and you're good

Comment: Good idea, Jeremy. I'm not too keen on nesting two tables for layout purposes, so I have wrapped the content in two successive divs, defining the article and the two containing divs as display:table, display:table-row and display:table-cell, respectively. It works as expected, thanks!